# How do I style a selected option string with 2 different colors using CSS?

Tags: html, css

I have a dropdown select element with car names and their available colors inside parentheses. I would like to be able to do something like this:

```
<select class="cars">
   <option>Rolls Royce Phantom <span class="car-color">(silver)</span></option>
   <option>Ferrari 488GTB <span class="car-color">(yellow)</span></option>
   <option>Chevrolet Camaro <span class="car-color">(black)</span></option>
</select>
```

where

```
.cars {
   color: black;
   font-weight: bold;
}
.car-color {
   color: grey;
   font-weight: normal;
}
```

This code above is not working, unfortunately. How do I reach a desired effect?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to style the option of a html "select"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7208786/how-to-style-the-option-of-a-html-select)

Answer (score 2):

You can't style `option` elements because it's rendered by the **OS**, not **HTML**. That is why it can't be styled via **CSS**.

Either you could use some plugins to reach what you are trying to do,

W3schools has a simple way to style the drop down, [check it here](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_dropdowns.asp).

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this

```
.carcolor{
    color: grey;
}

$('<option>').val('india').text('india').attr('class','carcolor')
.appendTo('#groupid');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like below css , First example is for all option and second is for specific nth child, if you have multiple styles

```css
.cars1,.cars2 {
   color: green;
   font-weight: bold;
}
.cars1 option{
   color: red;
   font-weight: normal;
   
}
.cars2 option:nth-child(2) {
   color: red;
   font-weight: normal;
}
```

```html
<select class="cars1">
   <option>Rolls Royce Phantom <span class="car-color">(silver)</span></option>
   <option>Ferrari 488GTB <span class="car-color">(yellow)</span></option>
   <option>Chevrolet Camaro <span class="car-color">(black)</span></option>
</select>
<br/><br/><br/>
<div></div>

<select class="cars2">
   <option>Rolls Royce Phantom <span class="car-color">(silver)</span></option>
   <option>Ferrari 488GTB <span class="car-color">(yellow)</span></option>
   <option>Chevrolet Camaro <span class="car-color">(black)</span></option>
</select>
```